# Can't replace backslashes in responseText?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I read many question on SO about replacing backslashes with javascript and tried them but they didn't work for me. The response text contains backslashes and i need to get rid of them but nothing worked?
Here is JS function to make requests:

```
  requestKittens: function() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    var xhr = event.target;


    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    var str = xhr.responseText;
    str.replace(/\\/g, '');
     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = xhr.responseText

    }
};

    req.open('GET', this.searchOnFlickr_, true);
        req.setRequestHeader('accessKey','fdsfkslfjslfjlgfdgdfg');


    req.send();
  },
```

This is the response from server

> {"topics":[{"topicLabel":"Computer
>   concepts","topicThesaurusName":"topics","topicUrl":"http://dictionary.cambridge.org/topics/technology/computer-concepts/","topicId":"computer-concepts","topicParentId":"technology"}],"dictionaryCode":"british","entryLabel":"address
>   noun (COMPUTERS)","entryContent":"address</h1> noun</span> [C</span></span>]</span></span> (COMPUTERS)</span>https://dictionary.cambridge.org/external/images/uk_pron.png?version=2013-08-07-1929\"/></a>https://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/british/uk_pron/u/uka/ukada/ukadapt021.mp3\"/>https://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/british/uk_pron_ogg/u/uka/ukada/ukadapt021.ogg\"/>Your
>   browser does not support HTML5 audio.</audio>https://dictionary.cambridge.org/external/images/us_pron.png?version=2013-08-07-1929\"/></a>https://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/british/us_pron/e/eus/eus70/eus70074.mp3\"/>https://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/british/us_pron_ogg/e/eus/eus70/eus70074.ogg\"/>Your
>   browser does not support HTML5 audio.</audio> /əˈdres</span>/</span>  /ˈæd.res</span>/</span>
>   </span></header>A1</span> </span>a series of
>   letters and symbols that tell you where to find something on the
>   internet or show where an email is sent to: </span></span>What's your email
>   address?</span></span>Do
>   you have their Web address?</span></span></section> \u203a</span> specialized</span></span></span> the place where a piece of information is stored in a
>   computer's memory</span></span></section>(Definition
>   of address noun (COMPUTERS) from the https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/\"
>   title=\"Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary &
>   Thesaurus\n\">Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary &
>   Thesaurus\n</a> © Cambridge University
>   Press)</small></footer></article>","entryUrl":"http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/address_2","format":"html","entryId":"address_2"}

What may cause the problem?

Comment: `str.replace(/\\/g, "")` will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
str = str.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

And:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: I thought str.replace() would affect str. Silly mistake.

Comment: @salihrkc yes it is common mistake ;) glad if it helps